# Browser is not smooth while using jQuery "replaceWith"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery replaceWith to update information of my website. Div elements which are returned are small. The function is called after 5 minutes. When I focus on browser, replaceWith function will run but my browser is not smooth and sometime can crash. Which plugin or solution can I use to resolve the problem ?
I used:

```
$('#hotpost').hide().html(newHtml).fadeIn("slow"); 
$('#hotpost div.content').hide().replaceWith(newHtml).fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using multiple replaceWith() instead of html() on a parent element?

Comment: I used: $('#hotpost').hide().html(newHtml).fadeIn("slow"); or $('#hotpost div.content').hide().replaceWith(newHtml).fadeIn("slow");

Comment: it depends on how you have set up the 5 minutes code :) have you used setTimeout? or setInterval ?

Comment: use the setTimeout. as that will go wait for the time to reach and then fire the event of if u prefer the method. interval should not be used to call the same function it seats in. :)

Comment: can use  $('#hotpostdiv.content').hide("slow").replaceWith(newHtml).fadeIn("slow");

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should compile your HTML into a document fragment
using for example, this function

```
var compileHTML = function (html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while ( div.firstChild ) {
        fragment.appendChild( div.firstChild );
    }
    return fragment
};
```

before appending your HTML into your new div
like so:

```
$('#hotpost').hide().html(compileHTML(newHtml)).fadeIn("slow");
```

Plus I saw that in your code you're usin setInterval which when blurring the window can have unexpected behaviours, you could use this:

```
(function loop(){
   //what you need to do
   $('#hotpost').hide().html(compileHTML(newHtml)).fadeIn("slow"); //for example
   setTimeout(loop, (18000));
 })();
```

this new loop will wait until the code inside is executed before looping again, rather than executing the code and ("no", says browser, "user is using memory in an other tab")
And when you go back to your page, multiple animations happen at the same time...

Comment: If you use the `append()` method, jQuery will internally use document fragments.

Comment: Oh yeah ! That's true ! Seeing How they've improved,if the only differences are the variable lookups I'll probably start using that then :)